# Is there a usecase for using get on Future object obtained from calling submit of runnable instance of executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

Executor service has following method -

```
Future<?> submit(Runnable task);
```

Now Runnable unlike Callabe does not return anything (its return type is void). So calling get on future object give me null for a Runnable task submitted.

```
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
    service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<?> result =  service.submit(() -> System.out.println("My 1st ThreadId : " + Thread.currentThread().getId()));
    System.out.println(result.get());
    } finally {
    if(service != null) service.shutdown();
    }
```

gives

```
My 1st ThreadId : 10
null
```

It would probably be a blocking call before it returns null if Runnable task is not over. Wondering if there is a practical usecase of using get on future object returned by calling submit to executor service for a runnable task.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest use case is simply waiting for the task to finish.  Usually done if you want to kick several things off in parallel and wait for them all to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Future.get()` has sense if you want to make sure the `Runnable` executed successfully, without any exception. If, however, an exception has occured, `get()` also would throw an (another) exception.